# What is the maximum temprature that could be achieved by compressing air?

Tags: compressed-air

We know that compressing air produces heat but is it possible to achieve temprature of 700degree C just by compressing air. If not what will be the maximum temprature that could be achieved?

Comment: What compression ratio could you achieve?

Comment: How well insulated is your system?

Comment: "compressing air produces heat" is not a correct thing to say.

Comment: Sure, start with 699 degree air and compress it a little.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "maximum," short of creating plasma.  The temperature obtained will be a function of compression ratio and insulation.   Other than that it is a simple T-P ratio (use kelvin or Rankine units).

Whether you can build a 400:1 compression ratio compressor is quite a different question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no set temperature that is the default maximum threshold obtainable via pneumatic compression as @Tiger Guy and @Transistor said. You could, however, think of a compressed air tank much like a bomb calorimeter, in that the air stored inside it represents the system, and the outside room/atmosphere the surroundings. The system in this case generates very little measurable heat that is not absorbed immediately by the metal tank and the surroundings.